# Возврат нуля в JSP

Tags: jsp

Имею следующее:

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    char[] charArray = reverse(request.getParameter("field").toCharArray());
    request.setAttribute("pro", charArray.toString());      
}

public char[] reverse(char[] array){
    int id = 0;
    char[] newArr = new char[array.length];
    for(int i=array.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
        newArr[id] = array[i];
        id++;
    }
    return newArr;      
}
```

JSP

```
<form action="MyServlet">
name="field" type="text" value="corvet"
type="submit" value="Send" onClick="alert(<%request.getAttribute("pro");%>)"
```

В алерт окне возвращает всегда Null. Подскажите, люди добрые, в чём дело.
Не пишу input, потому что код в кнопки преобразовывается.

Answer (score 1):

Вы в сервлете атрибут засовываете в сессию, а на страннице пытаетесь выращить из реквеста. Логично, что там его нет. Либо кладите атрибут в реквест, либо вытаскивайте его из сессии.

Comment: Теперь выдаёт просто пустое окно. Не может ли быть причина в том, что сначала выполняется событие onClick, а потом уже Servlet обрабатывает запрос? Можно каким-нибудь образом этого избежать?
Есть ли возможность просто вывести в алерт окне необходимый массив, не обрабатывая onClick? Знаю, как с GWT сделать, а вот как стандартными средствами - плечами пожимаю.

Comment: > Не может ли быть причина в том, что сначала выполняется событие onClick, а потом уже Servlet обрабатывает запрос?

Такого быть точно не может, JSP отрабатывает на сервере, присылая клиенту уже готовый HTML. Добавьте в вопрос ваш исправленный код.

> Есть ли возможность просто вывести в алерт окне необходимый массив, не обрабатывая onClick?

Конечно. Нужно просто вызывать `alert` в обработчике события `onLoad` страницы.

Comment: не могли бы вы привести пример, а то мозги уже совсем не варят

Comment: @Илья Белейчев, а вас не смущает тот факт, что вы вызываете `request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
` до того как устанавливаете значения атрибутов? Всё что вы делаете после `forward` просто теряется. Считайте `forward` аналогом `return`.